# Dynamically dropbox XML data from access

Tags: excel, xml, vba, ms-access, ribbonx

I have a custom menu (Ribbon) XML in Excel, I can dynamically place the items that are in the worksheet, but not the items of an access recordset. Tried collections, arrays and the recordset directly. Someone dynamically put the access data?

This code works by taking the values ​​of the cells and including in the dropbox.

[image]

```vb
returnedVal = Cells(index,1).value
```

I want to do the same inclusion procedure, but with the data coming from the access through the recordset.

```vb
'Callback for Dropdown1 getItemLabel
Sub GetDDItemLabel(control As IRibbonControl, index As Integer, ByRef returnedVal)

    Dim CN As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Banco As String
    Dim Senha As String
    Dim Func As Collection
    Dim i As Long
    Set Func = New Collection
    Set CN = New ADODB.Connection
    Banco = "C:\Users\excel\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Teste Funcionários.accdb"
    Senha = "senha"
    With CN
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .Properties("jet OLEDB:DataBase Password") = Senha
        .Mode = adModeReadWrite
        .Open Banco
    End With
    Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset
    RS.Open "SELECT * FROM [Funcionários]", CN, adOpenKeyset, _
                                 adLockPessimistic, adCmdText
    RS.Update
    Do Until RS.EOF
    Func.Add RS(1)
    RS.MoveNext
    Loop
    CN.Close
    returnedVal = Func.Item(index + 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are doing. What do you mean by "custom menu XML in Excel", "dynamically place items that are in the worksheet", "dynamically entered the data" - data from where to where?

Comment: `Func.Add RS(1)` adds the second *Field object* from the recordset to the collection `Func`.  Is that what you need?  Have you tried instead using `Func.Add RS(1).Value` ?  FYI it might help folks here to show a comparison of working example where you populate the menu from a worksheet.

Comment: I made some edits to the question, hope I was clearer

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: What does the following method returns in the code - `Func.Item(index + 1)`? Have you tried running the code under the debugger?